# Trouble at importing modules at NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend

I am doing a project in university using NestJS. It is a really nice project, but a friend of mine created the architecture, and I am having trouble in using the services.

[image]

This is the architecture of the project. I am responsible for the sign up and login of users, and I chose the JWT method (I am a beginner in backend). The strategy is located in the shared/auth directory. The thing is that I was planning on issuing the JWT Token in the controller, as I did in some tutorial projects, but I don't have the JWTModule in the User.module. It is only in the Auth.module. Should I just import the JWTModule in the User.module, and I'm good to go, or I am missing something?

I tried to import AuthService in User.module, but it just broke everything. I tried issuing the JWT Token in the controller, but I don't think it is a "good" practice. I tried to issue the JWT Token in the local strategy, but it gave me an error that I was honestly scared (something about PEM routines). I just don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't put any logic in the controllers and just pass the data to the corresponding service. I don't know a lot about best practices but based on my experience, Issuing a token is a part of the authentication system so you have to do it in `authService`. for example if you have a user/login route, `userController` should pass the data to login function in `userService` and login function just calls a function from `authService` for verifying credientials and issuing the token. for using `authService` in other modules, first of all you have to export `authService` from `authModule` and import `authModule` in the module that you want to user `authService`.
for more information check NestJS [authentication](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication) docs.

**userModule.ts**

```
@Module({
      imports: [
        AuthModule,
        ...
      ],
```

**authModule.ts**

```
@Module({
          ...
         exports: [JwtStrategy, PassportModule, AuthService],
})
```

**userService.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
    ) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem really is that I'm already import UserModule in the AuthModule, so I can't do what you told me.

Comment: @enricocaliolo It is better to change your logic so `Authmodule` be independent but if it's not the case you can use `forwardRef()` to make both modules dependent on each other, check [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency)

Comment: I did search and I found exactly this forwardRef() function, and it worked perfectly! Thanks mate!